# Django, comments cannot get the name of the post they are on

Tags: python, django, html, web, server

I'm having an issue with Python Django. It has to do with foreign keys and models. I have been told before that my questions are often incredibly mediocre, so please bear with me on this. I am trying to configure comments for a social network I'm working on and I've just got comments working, kind of. The issue is that, although I can input a comment and the database will log it and the person who wrote it, it won't log the post it is on. It always returns null. This is really the full extent of what I can say, as I REALLY don't understand what is happening. Here are a number of different code snippets and image that should hopefully be able to elaborate on the issue without requiring my interjection.

1:
The models of the post-app
https://pastebin.com/XXNsCa5g

The important model being:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
```

2:
The reply template:
https://pastebin.com/GsLUQqYp

3:
The reply view:

```
class PostReplyView(CreateView):
model = models.Comment
template_name = 'post_reply.html'
fields = ['comment']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Finally, a visual representation of what is missing from a comment when it is posted: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeCen.png)

Comment: maybe you need to include the post field in the fields attribute of the class

Answer (score 0):

Updated using normal view:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import MyUser
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s by %s" % (self.title, self.user.get_full_name())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s commented on %s" % (self.author, self.post)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment

class newPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','content']


class newComment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, slug=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = newComment(request.POST)
        if comment.is_valid():
            new_Comment = comment.save(commit=False)
            new_Comment.author = user
            new_Comment.post = post
            new_Comment.save()
            # successfully commented, now do whatever you want
            return HttpResponse('commented')
    else:
        comment = newComment()

    context = {
        'post' : post,
        'comment' : comment
    }
    return render(request, 'post/detail.html', context)
```

**detail.html**

```
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ post.content }}</p>

<hr>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ comment.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

** you are getting empty field on "post" because you are not linking it with any post, but in the above example i have shown you how i have done it and how you can also do the same for your project **

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not really too sure what I'm supposed to do with what you've shown me here. What specifically do I need to replace in the models.py file, and with what?

Comment: 1) You need to understand what fields you have inside the "Comment Model" and how many of them are "Foreign_key".

2) The only part where you are getting the error is because inside views.py if you see closely then you are linking one of your foreign_key (Author to the logged in user), but because you also have another foreign_key inside the model you need to link that foreign_key/field to the existing post too. 

3) you are using class based view, i will be updating my answer do check that out, it will cover how to link your comment with the corresponding post